# C# ReSharper: Possible infinite inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, resharper

Why does **ReSharper** give warning about **Possible infinite inheritance** on `IGeneric<TGeneric>` but not on `ISimple` interfaces?

```
// api

public interface INodeBase<TNode>
    where TNode : INodeBase<TNode>
{
    TNode Parent { get; set; }
    List<TNode> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface INode<TValue>
    : INodeBase<INode<TValue>>
{
    TValue Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IBelongToNodeBase<TOwner>
    where TOwner : INodeBase<TOwner>
{
    TOwner Owner { get; set; }
}

// All good
public interface ISimple
    : IBelongToNodeBase<INode<ISimple>>
{
}

// Possible infinite inheritance
public interface IGeneric<TGeneric>
    : IBelongToNodeBase<INode<IGeneric<TGeneric>>>
{
}
```

Could it be just an issue with ReSharper's intellisense? This comes from real case scenario and code compiles and runs without any issues.

Comment: Since it says "_possible_ infinite inheritance" I guess it's possible to declare a class implementing `IGeneric<TGeneric>` in a ways that does lead to infinite inheritance. But by no means I can get my head around these constructs.

Comment: the `ISimple` case is trivial, it's not generic. You should edit the question and use your `interface IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric> : INode<IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric>>` example. In this case the warning only appears on classes implementing the interface, but not on the interface itself like at `IGeneric<TGeneric>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.3/PossibleInfiniteInheritance.html) (provided by René), the ReSharper documentation raises this issue after three levels of nesting where a generic references itself.

> In a situation similar to the following:

```
class B<U>
{
}
class A<T> : B<A<A<T>>>
{
}
```

> You effectively end up with the type A that inherits an infinitely recursive type B. As a result, your assembly will compile, but you will be unable to execute it. If you try, you will get an error message similar to the following:
>
> Could not load type ‘ConsoleApplication1.A{{1' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it has recursive generic definition.

Comment: Then why this one does not give me a warning:
`interface IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric> : INode<IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric>>`
or this:
`interface IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric> : INodeBase<IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric>>`

Comment: @chainerlt, I think that'd be a support ticket with the Resharper team. You're right, those examples hypothetically should raise the same warning based on the samples provided

Comment: No I don't think so, in the not-working example the generic argument is nested a level deeper than in the working `INode<IGenericNoProblem<TGeneric>>` (ok, 2 level) vs `IBelongToNodeBase<INode<IGeneric<TGeneric>>>` (fail, 3 level). And the 3-level version is what r# show in its [explanation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.3/PossibleInfiniteInheritance.html)